# Trigger on View not firing on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen some articles mention the possibility of a Trigger on a View, triggering on either insert, updates or deletes to one of the base tables from which the View is created.

However I am not able to get a simple example to work.

```
CREATE TABLE [Test].[Data] (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    Data VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);
GO

CREATE VIEW [Test].[View] AS SELECT * FROM  [Test].[Data];
GO

CREATE TABLE [Test].[Queue] (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    DataId INT NOT NULL,
    Action VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER InsertTrigger ON [Test].[View] INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
    BEGIN   
        DECLARE @DataId INT;
        DECLARE @Timestamp DATETIME;
        SET @DataId = (SELECT Id FROM INSERTED);
        SET @Timestamp = GETDATE();

        INSERT INTO [Test].[Queue] (DataId, Action, Timestamp) VALUES (@DataId, 'Insert', @Timestamp)
    END
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER InsertTrigger ON [Test].[View];
GO

INSERT INTO [Test].[Data] (Data) VALUES ('Testdata');
```

The trigger is not firing, is the above not possible or is there something wrong with my Sql?

Edit: Although answered I would like to clarify the question. The idea was to get the trigger on the View to fire, when there was an Insert to the base table and not the View itself.

Comment: The trigger's on the view though, isn't it? You're not inserting into the view.

Comment: No, I am not inserting into the View itself. The View is a summary from other tables, for example, the View “Cars” created from the tables “Tesla”, “Chrysler”, etc. When there is a change to “Tesla” I need to do some processing, which is why I want to insert the change into a queue. The idea was to save a lot of triggers by creating a Trigger on an already existing View.

Comment: Perhaps I should state it more clearly: a trigger on a view will only work on inserts into that view. You're not inserting into that view, you're inserting into a table.

Comment: Ahh I understand, thank you. If you create an answer I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Beware: Triggers in SQL Server are fired per statement, not per rows. This means that once you attempt to execute an insert statement that will insert multiple rows to the view, the trigger will either throw an error or worst - yield some unexpected results. `Inserted` is a table and it might contain 0, 1, or multiple rows.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't read it all in detail, what Zohar tells you is very relevant.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Noted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger on a view will only work on inserts into that view, not on any inserts into tables to which the view references.

In your script you're not inserting into that view, you're inserting into a table.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to not testing this correctly, your view is wrong.  You are not considering that `inserted` represents multiple rows, not one.

So:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertTrigger ON [Test].[View] INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
BEGIN   

    INSERT INTO [Test].[Queue] (DataId, Action, Timestamp)
        SELECT i.Id, 'Insert', GETDATE()
        FROM Inserted; 
END;

GO

INSERT INTO [Test].[View] (Data)
    VALUES ('Testdata');
```

Comment: I might be reading your comment wrong, but my knowledge was insufficient (hence the question) and thus the View (or more correct the whole idea) was wrong.

Comment: @andreasnauta . . . The idea is not wrong.   You can write triggers on views.  But you should be using correct trigger code.

Comment: I have tried to clarify the question for future searches. I now know, you can write triggers on views, but not get the trigger to trigger when data is inserted into the referenced table, which was I thought.